# Webkit API for Safari, Iphone

Tags: iphone, safari, webkit

I went to the webkit.org and, honestly saying, the site doesn't provide any tutorial or documentation of the API.

I'm looking for what new CSS, and DOM webkit provides.

Anyone know where I can find the information?

Comment: Que pasa? It's “iPhone”, not “Iphone” fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Supported CSS Properties](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/appleapplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html) list for Safari, which supports the same properties as WebKit. Also, WebKit supports all of CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

Apple maintains a Safari Developer Library at https://developer.apple.com/libary/safari/

For CSS you can read the [Safari CSS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Introduction.html), for DOM updates the [WebKit DOM Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/index.html) is your best choice (though lacking some detail for sure)